# Which MySQL settings are the closest equivalent to RDS' "Queue depth"?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, amazon-rds, storage

I'm trying to find out which MySQL status variables can be used to get as close as possible to the RDS value of "Queue depth".

On a test system, I reckon that `%pending%` variables may be at least a part of it:

```sql
mysql> show global status like '%pending%';
+------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                |
+------------------------------+----------------------+
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs   | 18446744073709551615 |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads    | 0                    |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes   | 0                    |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs | 0                    |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes | 0                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------+
```

although in this case, `Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs` is clearly a bogus value.

Assuming I'm on an InnoDB-only setup, which are the values that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: It can't have an equivalent because I/O queue depth is a metric of the storage device (or its driver), not the database engine.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is probably the 64-bit unsigned value equivalent to `-1`.  Still a bogus value.

Comment: The "pending" values are transient.  What do you hope to gain from them?  That is, tell us what `Queue depth` means, and why you care about it.

Comment: I was hoping to get some MySQL metric that indicates excess (pending) I/O; I'm aware of using `Threads_running` as a very generic metric, but I was looking for something more storage-related.